# Cannot find module './app/server.app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I get the following error while building Angular aot :

Cannot find module './app/server.app.module.ngfactory'

Can you help to determine what might be wrong?

main.server.aot.ts that contains the following :

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as express from 'express';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerAppModuleNgFactory } from './ngfactory/app/server-app.module.ngfactory';

enableProdMode();
const app = express();

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: ServerAppModuleNgFactory
}));

require('./main.server.shared').confApp(app);
```

this is tsconfig.server.aot

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.server.json",
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "ngfactory",
    "entryModule": "./app/server-app.module#ServerAppModule"
  },
  "include": [
    "main.server.aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

[project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfTNE.png)

Comment: is this file in your project server-app.module.ngfactory?

Comment: It should be generated

this is tsconfig.server

{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.server.json",
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "ngfactory",
    "entryModule": "./app/server-app.module#ServerAppModule"
  },
  "include": [
    "main.server.aot.ts"
  ]
}

Comment: please see the post after edits

Comment: please confirm , is the `server-app.module.ngfactory` file getting generating when you are building your project?

Comment: also which version of angular are you using?

Comment: No, it is not generated.
I use Angular 4

Comment: Share your code on stackblitz.

Comment: Sorry I cannot share it as it is a company project with privileges. I hope if you can tell me what could cause such a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

As you cant share the code , Suggest you to follow the steps mentioned [here](https://blog.squareboat.com/how-to-implement-server-side-rendering-using-angular-4-5da10f4dcb61). See the differences in your configuration.

Few Suggestions :

```
    1. No need of "genDir": "ngfactory" . Remove it from tsconfig.server.json
    2. Lazy import :  const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');
    3. Server.ts -
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// Our index.html we'll use as our template
const template = readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html')).toString();

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

const { provideModuleMap } = require('@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader');

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    // DI so that we can get lazy-loading to work differently (since we need it to just instantly render it)
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check and reply.